# how to tell ascii to send character and not code

Tags: javascript

How can i make ASCII send what is typed than code.

I mean if A is type on a keyboard the result on php should be the letter typed and not the Code

```
var ucode = function(s) {

    var len = s.length;
    var rs = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var k = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        rs += "$" + (s.charCodeAt(i) + "1") + ";";
    }
    return rs;
};
```

Comment: If this is java, then what was I doing for years...?

Comment: i am working on a page with a form. when the user type there password what i get is an ascii code, i want to get the actual letter to be sent to my myfile.php and not this code any help please

Comment: it is javascript, not java.